# Location only refreshes when I turn GPS off

Tags: android, gps

So I have a problem when trying to resolve my location. When given the command to find my location, it instead gives me the last location of where I turned my GPS off. Being able to find my coarse location using WiFi also seems to not be working.

Here is my current class

```
public class LocationTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {


//flag for GPS Status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

//flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

boolean canGetLocation = false;
Location location;
double latitude;
double longitude;

//The minimum distance to change updates in metters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; //10 metters

//The minimum time beetwen updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

//Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;



public void fetchLocation(Context context) {
    contextnormal = context;
    getLocation(context);
    if (canGetLocation())
    {
        String stringLatitude = String.valueOf(latitude);
        String stringLongitude = String.valueOf(longitude);
        Log.i("Location: ", stringLatitude + " " + stringLongitude);        
    }
    else
    {
        // can't get location
        // GPS or Network is not enabled
        // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
        Log.i("Error: ", "Cannot get location");
    }
}


public Location getLocation(Context context)
{
    try
    {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        //getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled)
        {
            // no network provider is enabled
        }
        else
        {
            this.canGetLocation = true;

            //First get location from Network Provider
            if (isNetworkEnabled)
            {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                Log.d("Network", "Network");

                if (locationManager != null)
                {
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    updateGPSCoordinates();
                }
            }

            //if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled)
            {
                if (location == null)
                {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");

                    if (locationManager != null)
                    {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        updateGPSCoordinates();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Error : Location", "Impossible to connect to LocationManager", e);
    }

    return location;
}

public void updateGPSCoordinates()
{
    if (location != null)
    {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 */

public void stopUsingGPS()
{
    if (locationManager != null)
    {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(LocationTracker.this);
    }
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 */
public double getLatitude()
{
    if (location != null)
    {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 */
public double getLongitude()
{
    if (location != null)
    {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 */
public boolean canGetLocation()
{
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
{   
     //Want to Execute Asynctask method to HTTP post the lat and long. Is there a way `to pass in a context to do this?`
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) 
{   
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) 
{   
    if (contextnormal != null) {
        fetchLocation(contextnormal);
    }
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) 
{   
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
{
    return null;
}
```

I would guess the problem lies in these lines

```
  if (isGPSEnabled)
                    {
                        if (location == null)
                        {
                            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                    MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                    MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                            Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");

                            if (locationManager != null)
                            {
                                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                                updateGPSCoordinates();
                            }
                        }
```

And for some reason it is giving the last known location as the last time the GPS was turned on. Any ideas as to why it is doing that instead of giving the last known location as the present location if the GPS is on?

EDIT:

Implementing the following method and testing:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
{   
    double newLat = location.getLatitude();
    double newLong = location.getLongitude(); 
    String stringNewLatitude = String.valueOf(newLat);
    String stringNewLongitude = String.valueOf(newLong);
    new MyAsyncTask().execute(stringNewLatitude, stringNewLongitude);   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just query the location manager for its last known location repeatedly, that will only get you the last known location. It sounds like what you are trying to do is get location updates as you move around.

In this case, you will need to register for location updates, as you tried with your line:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
```

You are on the right track here, but what is `this` (the last argument on the function call [yes I know it is a reference to the current class...])? The last argument is supposed to be an intent or a callback where the updates will be broadcast to. It doesn't appear that you have implemented that from the code you provided.

Change your `this` argument to a class which implements [LocationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html). The location updates will come to the `onLocationChanged` method where you can then process them as you see fit. A simple way to do this is to add a nested inner class which implements the listener, then you can just create an instance of that class and pass it to the location manager, in place of your current `this` argument.

**EDIT**

OK, so you are implementing the thing correctly, but blisfully ignoring the location updates, don't do that. The service you have *is* a `Context` -- so you can pass that around as you see fit, although it may be better to use:

```
this.getApplicationContext();
```

If you are passing it to some long running thing. What I would recommend is to queue your location updates when the arrive in `onLocationChanged()`. After queuing the location, signal a background worker thread (or AsyncTask) to actually post the location to your web service.

Also, don't override `onBind` and return null. Just don't override it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't post the full code. The class i'm writing currently implements LocationListener and had the onLocationChanged method overridden but wasn't doing anything with it. My post is updated with the full code now. I have an Asynctask written inside the class that I would like to pass the Lat and Long from onLocationChanged to, but it requires a context. How could I pass that in? Thanks!

Comment: A `Service` is a context, you can use `this` as you have before (`this.getApplicationContext()` might be better). I will amend my answer with further suggestions.

Comment: See edit in OP, going to try that code out. Thanks for your help so far!